# Formal "attaching to the e-mail" in German

Tags: word-usage, phrase, formality

On [linguee.de](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=attach%20to%20email) I've found a very good translation for *attach*:

> ..., die Sie *an* E-Mail-Nachrichten *anhängen* möchten.

So, *anhängen* is the translation for *attach*.

In real life we usually type to someone:

> Attaching a document to the *(this)* email.

This question is more on formality.

Would it be okay if I type for example:

> Mein Lebenslauf hänge ich an diesem E-Mail an.

Is there a more formal way to say the same?

Comment: "Im Anhang finden sie..."

Comment: I use the feniminine artice for E-Mail, thus, I would say: "Mein Lebenslauf hänge ich an _diese_ E-Mail an". Is it also correct to say _diesem_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution looks ok except that you have to write *Meinen*. A little bit more elaborate and perhaps smoother you could write:

> Meinen Lebenslauf füge ich der E-mail als Anlage hinzu.

Comment: Nice suggestion. Sounds very good as well.

Comment: @a-herrmann see my comment on the accepted answer for a longer explanation of this.

Comment: @a-herrmann It is spelled "E-Mail" (big M). And actually I wouldn't recommend to say "hinzufügen" instead of "anhängen". *Anhängen* is exactly the right term for this and is definitely preferred. 5pike's answer has another idiomatic (and completely correct) solution.

Comment: Oder "beifügen".

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

> Mein Lebenslauf hänge ich an diesem E-Mail an.

I'd write

> Mein Lebenslauf befindet sich im Anhang.

While not really that formal, it's commonly used and perfectly fine, even for applications.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be perfect!

Comment: @FelixDombek: I think, in your last example, "Meinen Lebenslauf hänge ich dieser E-Mail an.", E-Mail is actually dative. Replace it by a masculine word: "Diese Seite hänge ich dem Leitfaden an." It's *dem* Leitfaden (dative), not *des* Leitfadens (genitive).

Comment: Note that "Mein Lebenslauf" is nominative; in the first example, the Lebenslauf is the object (which is BEING attached) and you need the accusative "Meinen Lebenslauf...". Also, you got the gender and grammatical case of E-Mail wrong. "Anhängen an" needs dative and E-Mail is feminine, that means "diese E-Mail". (Thanks Oguk)

Comment: I hope I do not confuse you totally if I offer another grammatical construction that is very similar to the first: "Meinen Lebenslauf hänge ich dieser E-Mail an." This has E-Mail in the genitive case and skips the preposition "an" (because "anhängen" can be used both ways.)

Comment: E-Mail ist feminin, regional auch neutrum ([Duden1](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/E_Mail)); @FelixDombek anhängen an wird in dieser Bedeutung mit dem Akkusativ gebildet ([Duden2](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anhaengen_schwaches_Verb), Bedeutung 3). Es müsste also vollständig heißen: "Meinen Lebenslauf hänge ich an diese E-Mail an." Klingt in meinen Ohren aber komisch, also lieber "Meinen Lebenslauf habe ich angehängt." oder "[...] beigefügt." oder "[...] finden Sie im Anhang."